# How can I monitor a wi-fi device communication like monitoring an Ethernet-linked device using port-mirroring switch and WireShark?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

In an Ethernet network, it's well-known to connect devices with a port-mirroring switch and then watch communication among devices using WireShark. Before WireShark can capture packets from other ports, port mirroring must be set first.

But, is there similar methods to monitor the communication of a device that connects to the same wi-fi AP with the monitoring computer which runs WireShark?

Answer (score 1):

Connect the AP to an Ethernet switch with port-mirroring, then use the existing procedure. (If you need to monitor traffic between two Wi-Fi devices, connect them to separate SSIDs on two different APs, with Ethernet in between.)

If the AP provides SSH access, it might have a packet capture feature built in (e.g. UniFi firmwares run Linux and include tcpdump which can be streamed via SSH; RouterOS devices have /tool/packet-sniffer which supports UDP streaming).

Comment: Do you mean to set the switch port connecting to AP as a mirror port? Then, all communication coming thru the wi-fi device which connects to the AP (connecting to the port mirroring switch) will be monitored at the monitor port of the switch?